# Fazer consulta à BD e mostrar todos os resultados menos o primeiro

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a tabela `tbl_galeria`, o que acontece é que quero fazer uma consulta, mas a consulta não pode mostrar o primeiro resultado. Ou seja, a consulta vai retornar todos os valores menos o que tem o id menor.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_galeira ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Já agora tente utilizar a função [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) uma vez que a [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) será descontinuada.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer com o `MIN` do MySQL:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_galeira WHERE id > (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tbl_galeira) ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Answer (score 4):

Solução simples e direta sem subquery:

```
$query = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM tbl_galeira ORDER BY id LIMIT 1,999999999' ).
```

Basta o segundo parâmetro do `LIMIT` ser absurdamente maior do que a sua aplicação pretende armazenar. Lembre-se que 0 é o primeiro registro, então usamos 1 para pegar do segundo em diante.

<sub>Pode parecer estranha a sintaxe, porém é mais eficaz do que o *engine* comparar IDs linha a linha (além de mais legivel).</sub>

Comment: Eu pensei exatamente na mesma solução, mas eu fico um bocado apreensivo com o valor máximo ser um valor, e não uma constante tipo MAX_VAL.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu dei uma pesquisada antes de responder, cada engine tem um jeito diferente de trabalhar, e realmente não achei  nenhuma variável com essa função. De qualquer forma, provavelmente se um usuário precisar de uma query realista com mais de 999999999 registros de retorno de uma vez, deve ter problemas em alguma outra parte da aplicação (lembrando que o número é um exemplo e pode ser aumentado). Sua observação realmente é válida, de qq forma.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer uma subconsulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_galeira, 
    (SELECT id as fId FROM tbl_galeira ORDER BY id ASC limit 1) f 
WHERE id > f.fId
```

Answer (score 0):

É interessante saber quantos registros você quer retornar. Digamos que sejam 10, você faria o seguinte:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_galeira ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10, 1");
```

Comment: Ao contrário...  "LIMIT 1, 10" rsrsr

Comment: sim, mas eu nunca vou saber ao certo o limite de registos. obrigado na mesma!